# ASP.NET Core 1.1 Url Rewriting - www to non-www

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here's the core I use with ASP.NET Core 1.1 Url Rewriting middleware to redirect from www. to non-www:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("^(www\\.)(.*)$", "$2");
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

and for some reason it doesn't work. I know regex is correct. What's wrong here?

Here's the complete Configure function:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions() { DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ru-ru") });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            // URL Rewriting
            var options = new RewriteOptions()
                //.AddRedirect(@"^(https?:\/\/)(www\.)(.*)$", "$1$3");
                .AddRedirect("^(www\\.)(.*)$", "$2");
            app.UseRewriter(options);

            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{action=Index}/{id?}",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Home" }
                   );
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you sure the regex is correct? "www\\" means something like "www\.example.com". By the way [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/g7pU6F/1) could help you.

Comment: Yes, this is correct - ^(www\.)(.*)$  ,  I have to escape "dot"

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt The \\ is for the C# string, which converts to \ for regex.

Comment: Okay, it seems like strange. According to [this example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/) you are doing it correctly. Maybe we need to include the protokoll somehow? Does the msdn example work for you (Removing trailing slash)? Just assuming... Core is on my todo list.

Comment: How does it not work - is it just ignored? Can you paste all the relevant parts of your `Configure` method?

Comment: here's the whole method - hm, doesn't allow me post it here. says too long. how so I post the whole method?

Comment: but there's nothing special in my Configure method

Comment: here we go - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb063075ff9ce426ca1a496211492054

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/196

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the .AddRedirect and .AddRewrite only look at the path/query string of a URL. So your regex is correct, however the method is only looking at the path/query, so it will never see www. This behavior is standard to most rewriters, like Apache mod_rewrite and IIS UrlRewrite. However, this use case should be easily supported and we will look into it soon!

For now, to get your expected behavior, you can create a custom rule like this. Note I can't test the code at this moment, but the general idea should be right.

```
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(ctx =>
        {
            // checking if the hostName has www. at the beginning
            var req = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
            var hostName = req.Host;
            if (hostName.ToString().StartsWith("www."))
            {
                // Strip off www.
                var newHostName = hostName.ToString().Substring(4);

                // Creating new url
                var newUrl = new StringBuilder()
                                      .Append(req.Scheme)
                                      .Append(newHostName)
                                      .Append(req.PathBase)
                                      .Append(req.Path)
                                      .Append(req.QueryString)
                                      .ToString();

                // Modify Http Response
                var response = ctx.HttpContext.Response;
                response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = newUrl;
                response.StatusCode = 301;
                ctx.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
            }
        }));
```

Comment: I still needed to add `://`.
`var newUrl = $"{request.Scheme}://{domain}{request.PathBase}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";`